# Recursion optimization?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica, ocaml, compiler-optimization

Why does Fibonacci recursive procedure works so long?

This is in OCaml:

```
let rec fib n = if n<2 then n else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2);;
```

This is in Mathematica:

```
Fib[n_] := If[n < 2, n, Fib[n - 1] + Fib[n - 2]]
```

This is in Java:

```
public static BigInteger fib(long n) {
    if( n < 2 ) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    }
    else {
        return fib(n-1).add(fib(n-2));
    }
}
```

For `n=100` it works for a long time, because, I guess, it traces tree with `2^100` nodes in time.

Although, there are only 100 numbers to generate, so it could consume just 100 memory registers and 100 calculation tacts.

So, execution could be optimized.

What does this task about and how is it solved? Since solution does not implemented in Mathematica it probably doesn't exist. What about research on this matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a classic example used to show the value of [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). So, that's one approach to make it go faster.

(If you just want to calculate fibonacci quickly, of course it's extremely easy to rewrite the function to get the answer very fast. Start from 0 and work up to n, passing the previous 2 fibonacci numbers each time.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to go is memoization as in the answer by @JeffreyScofield.
Define :

```
Fib2[n_] := Fib2[n] = If[n < 2, n, Fib2[n - 1] + Fib2[n - 2]]
```

Check :

```
Fib[30] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {9.202920, 832040} *)

Fib2[30] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0., 832040} *)

Fib2[100] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.001000, 354224848179261915075} *)
```

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out an idea? Why does this work faster? May I define each recursive function as `F[n_]:=F[n]=body` and gain from memoization?

Comment: The idea of memoization is you don't recalculate "old" values because they are stored in memory (this is done with the `Fib2[n_] := Fib2[n]` bit) like a variable. It it not always appropriate to use memoization because it uses more memory and it might not be worth it if the calculation is fast.

Comment: This is Mathematica trick to turn memoization on or this is explainable behavior in terms of standard Mathematica evaluation procedure?

Comment: @SuzanCioc It is standard Mathematica evaluation. It can be used for memoization but also other things. More here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-is-x-x-trickery

Answer (score -2):

For a recursive Fibonacci sequence even for n=100 it should not take that much time to operate. Whether it is recursive or iterative it should still execute in O(N) time because all it is doing is summing up the previous numbers which is done in constant time. Approximately how long does it take to compute?

Comment: Try it! It will take a long time because it recalculates all the intermediate values repeatedly. One way to see it is to see that the only number that gets added without a recursive call is 1. But fib grows exponentially. So it takes an exponential time to add all those 1s.

Comment: I hadn't finished waiting. Dozens of minutes at least. Not 100 calclulations.

Comment: On my laptop (64-bit native code, 2.6 GHz) the OCaml function takes 70 seconds to calculate fib 50. It should be growing by phi (around 1.6) for each new number, and indeed fib 51 takes 114 seconds.